# Does importing a Python file also import the imported files into shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am running Python 3.6.2 and trying to import other files into my shell prompt as needed. I have the following code inside my_file.py.

```
import numpy as np
def my_file(x):
    s = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return s
```

From my 3.6.2 shell prompt I call

```
from my_file import my_file
```

But in my shell prompt if I want to use the library numpy I still have to import numpy into the shell prompt even though I have imported a file that imports numpy. Is this functionality by design? Or is there a way to import numpy once?

Comment: You have imported it into an other namespace. That is design. You can use it in that namespace only unless you import it elsewhere.

Comment: You could reference it as `my_file.np`.  But doing your own `import numpy` doesn't cost anything extra in time or memory usage.   Python checks a cache for already imported modules: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache

Comment: @hpaulj - So in the Python shell you are saying when I import my_file.py that I am creating a new namespace?  And that Python is smart enough to not import it twice but instead just adds it as a reference when I call it in another namespace?

Answer (score 4):

`import` has three completely separate effects:

1. **If** the module has not yet been imported in the current process (by any script or module), execute its code (usually from disk) and store a module object with the resulting classes, functions, and variables.
2. **If** the module is in a package, (import the package first, and) store the new module as an attribute on the containing package (so that references like `scipy.special` work).
3. Assign the module ultimately imported to a **variable** in the invoking scope.  (`import foo.bar` assigns `foo`; `import baz.quux as frob` assigns `baz.quux` to the name `frob`.)

The first two effects are shared among all clients, while the last is completely local.  This is by design, as it avoids accidentally using a dependency of an imported module without making sure it’s available (which would break later if the other modules changed what they imported).  It also lets different clients use different shorthands.

As [hpaul noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250013/does-importing-a-python-file-also-import-the-imported-files-into-shell#comment91448234_52250013), you *can* use another module’s imports with a qualified name, but this is abusing the module’s interface just like any other use of a private name unless (like `six.moves`, for example, or `os.path` which is actually not a module at all) the module *intends* to publish names for other modules.